# Дропдаун изменяющейся ширины в Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Верстаю макет на Bootstrap (по возможности использую только скрипты из Bootstrap). Навигационный сайдбар сделан аккордеоном, при клике на каждый пункт навигации должен вправо выпадать дропдаун, высотой равный высоте аккордеона, а ширина его должна изменяться в зависимости от количества пунктов меню в нем (их может быть довольно много).
Т.е. в дропдауне список произвольной длины, который должен автоматически вписываться в заданную высоту. Вопрос с высотой решил с помощью `position: absolute;` относительно аккордеона, но не получается сделать ширину дропдауна больше ширины сайдбара.

```html
<div class="content container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="sidebar col-sm-3">
  <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">Заголовок аккордеона</div>
                   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <ul class="panel-body nav-pills nav-stacked nav">
                             <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="sidebar-drop-1" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Пункт меню</a>
        <ul class="sidebar-dropdown dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="sidebar-drop-1">
         <li><a href="#">Подменю 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Подменю 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Подменю 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Подменю 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Подменю 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Подменю 6</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Подменю 7</a></li>
        </ul>
                             </li>
                          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">Заголовок сайдабара №2</div>
                           <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <ul class="panel-body">
                                      ...
                                </ul>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div> <!--accordion end-->
        </div><!--sidebar end-->
        <div class="main-content col-sm-9">
          ....
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Прошу простить за лютое форматирование - старался максимально сократить количество кода, а теперь не могу понять как здесь нормально его отформатировать.